# Can jQuery jTable have AutoWidth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-jtable

Would it be possible to have jQuery's jTable column to have it on autowidth or anything similar??

It's kind of a pest to resize it manually.
The width delcaration width: '20%' doesn't really work very well too so... Hope someone have an idea of what to do.

Comment: `bautowidth=true` try that ha ?>

Comment: @supercool will give it a go~

Comment: if you don't put anything on the `width` attribute of the fields, it will autowidth by itself. have you tried that?